# Taylor expansion, problematic integrand

Tags: complex-analysis, taylor-expansion

Consider
$$f(z) = \int_0^z \frac{1-\cos\sqrt{t}}{t}\mbox{d}t $$
Find its Taylor series at $a=0$. I was thinking about looking at the integrand, from which we would have:
$$\frac{1-\cos\sqrt{t}}{t} = \frac{1-\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k}{(2k)!}t^{k}} {t} = \frac{1}{t} - \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k}{(2k)!}t^{k-1} $$
but then if we integrate
$$\left (\ln t -\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k}{(2k)!k}t^k\right )\bigg|_0^z =\mbox{does not compute} $$

What have I done wrong?

Comment: The first term inside the summation cancels out the 1/t term.

Comment: Or directly $1-\cos(\sqrt t)=-\sum_{k=\color{red}1}(-t)^k/(2k)!$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$
\begin{align}
f(z) &= \int_0^z \frac{1-\cos\sqrt{t}}{t}\mathrm{d}t=\int_0^z \frac{1}{t}\Big(1-\overbrace{\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k}{(2k)!}t^{k}}^{1-\frac{t}{2!}+\frac{t^2}{4!}+\cdots}\Big)\mathrm{d}t\\ &=\int_0^z   \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{(2k)!}t^{k-1}\mathrm{d}t=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{(2k)!}\frac{z^k}{k}
\end{align}
$$

Comment: at the evaluation you mean $z^k$, but thank you, I understand now.